# How to test .map() function in NestJS and Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to test the next function in my service in **NestJS** and **Jest**. This is an extract of the function

```
async getAllUserEcgs(
    userId: string,
    page: number,
    pageSize: number,
  ): Promise<Ecg[]> {
    const ecgs = await this.ecgModel
      .aggregate([{ $match: { user: userId } }])
      .sort({ date: 1 })
             .
             .
             .

      .exec();

    const ecgsDecrypted = ecgs.map(
      (ecg: Ecg) =>
        ({
          date: ecg.date,
          user: ecg.user,
          _id: ecg._id,
          heartRate: parseInt(decrypt(ecg.heartRate)),
          hasAnomaly: JSON.parse(decrypt(ecg.hasAnomaly)),
          values: JSON.parse(
            decrypt(JSON.stringify(ecg.values)),
          ).map((el: string) => parseFloat(el)),
          count: ecg.count,
        } as Ecg),
    );

    return ecgsDecrypted;
  }
```

Once the aggregate query is executed I have to decrypt the result, an array of objects as you can see in the **map()** function.
I am trying to test this part

```
it('should return all ecgs', async () => {
      const ecgs = [
        {
          values: [463, 684, 1115, 502, 1094, 734, 701, 1126, 1034, 550],
          _id: '5e6b499ba92272007d49b7d7',
          date: '2020-01-18T06:42:10.836Z',
          hasAnomaly: true,
          heartRate: 117,
          user: 'BRqklWMs9aMX27sC5FaveE1srid2',
        },
        {
          values: [467, 681, 111, 574, 157, 754, 771, 116, 104, 550],
          _id: '5e6b499ba92272007d49b7d7',
          date: '2020-02-18T06:42:10.836Z',
          hasAnomaly: true,
          heartRate: 111,
          user: 'BRqklWMs9aMX27sC5FaveE1syn3d',
        },
      ];

      expect(ecgService.getAllUserEcgs('user', 1, 2)).resolves.toEqual({
        currentPage: lastEcg.currentPage,
        pageCount: lastEcg.pageCount,
        total: lastEcg.total,
        ecgs: ecgs.map(ecg => ({
             _id: sampleMock.ecg._id,
              heartRate: parseInt(JSON.parse(decrypt('heartRate'))),
              hasAnomaly: JSON.parse(decrypt('hasAnomaly')),
              values: JSON.parse(decrypt('values')),
        })),
      });  
  });
```

But I have the next error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: It seems the `const ecgs` inside the `getAllUserEcgs` function is undefined. But the question does not reveal enough about the code to know why. Check the returns of each function in the chain perhaps

Comment: Don't you try to compare an array with an object in the test? Can it be that the the error occurs in the function itself and not in the test?